# Multiple select option text standing under the checkbox in materialize.css

Tags: html, css, checkbox, materialize

In the example you see below, the text (Faculty not selected) stands under the checkbox, i didn't get any special features when i checked the attributes from style palette. Normally text should be near the checkbox. Any idea about the problem?

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row mt50">
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <select class="validate faculty" name="faculty" id="faculty" onchange="getCourse();">
                    <option value="">Choose</option>
                    <option value="FEng">Faculty of Engineering</option>
                    <option value="FMed">Faculty of Medicine</option>
                    <option value="FSci">Faculty of Science</option>
                </select>
                <label for="faculty">Faculty</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s4">
                <select name="course" id="course" multiple>
                    <option value="" disabled>Faculty not selected</option>
                <select/>
                <label for="course">Course</label>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle or working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add either display:inline or display:flex on #course. Something is probably making the checkbox display:block by default.